# how do i add extern file to google closure compiler for minification and prevent jquery names from being minified

Tags: jquery, google-closure-compiler

I have this link for extern file:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js

How do i include it into google closure compiler. 
https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

I want to prevent jquery function from getting minified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`externs_url`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref#externs_url) parameter.

For example:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @externs_url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```